# What are these strange lines that are visible at sunset?

Tags: lens, iphone, lens-flare, sunset

I see those lines, you see on the picture, on my iPhone 7 jumping random on my display while taking pictures. It was sunset right in the sea in Zakynthos. I would like to know what that is.

[image: Strange lines on picture]

Comment: Are those lines appear when you have direct view to the sun?

Answer (score 7):

It's called *lens flare*. Light from the sun that is just out of frame is striking the surface of your camera's lens or surrounding  housing and bouncing around inside the lens. Some of that light is included in the part of the image circle that falls on the camera's sensor.

There are many different types of lens flare. In addition to the more well known cases of veiling (a general lose of contrast over a portion or even all of an image), ghosting (an inverted and flipped reflection of a bright highlight within the frame directly across the center of the image from the primary highlight), and specular (those 'circles' that show the shape of the lens' aperture diaphragm) there are other, less common types of flare.

This example, in a photo released by NASA, was taken by the Mars Perseverance Rover. [NASA had to clarify to many people who thought they were seeing a photo of a rainbow in the very thin, very dry atmosphere of Mars that the "rainbow" was the effect of lens flare](https://www.space.com/perseverance-rover-mars-rainbow-photo).

[image]

If one looks at the iPhone 7 Plus, the housing (rotated 90° for landscape orientation) around the lenses is shaped much like the lower flare in your photo.

[image]

The upper flare, above the horizon, is a separate flare that is a section of an arc oriented towards the sun as we would expect with the edge of a round lens. The upper flare is marked by a blue oval with a  line drawn towards the sun to show that the arc is the "bow" we would expect for the line's "arrow" often seen with flare.

The lower flare is marked with a yellow oval (that covers part, but not all of it). It looks suspiciously like the shape of the edge of the cover glass over the entire lens assembly.

[image]

Reducing lens flare is the reason many lenses for interchangeable lens cameras use hoods. The hood prevents stray light from out of frame from falling on the front of the lens. Unfortunately, with a phone camera any kind of hood would require a protrusion out from the phone's surface.

Comment: You think he means those ones at the top?  I thought he meant the giant one that seems to start at the horizon and the one above that.  Probably also flares of a sort, but perhaps due to lens scratches rather than what one would normally see for such a lens.  At least I've never seen a lens in decent condition with such a strange curved flare.  Could also be something on the lens flaring.

Comment: @J... Phone lenses are made a bit differently than larger interchangeable lenses, thus the characteristics of their flare is different. Flare produced by scratches is still flare, it's just a different type of flare from veiling or ghosting or other types of flare more typical of traditional lenses. But I'm not convinced this is caused by a surface scratch. It could also be due to the unconventional way some camera phones use 'periscope' type construction to stretch out a focal length longer than the thickness of the phone.

Comment: @ttbek I'm primarily concerned with the line that runs from the horizon to the lower left corner.

Comment: @ttbek Please see this example of lens flare identified by NASA from one of their Mars rovers which many folks want to believe is a rainbow (in the very dry, very thin air of Mars): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_flare#/media/File:MarsPerseveranceRover-Rainbow-20210404.png

Comment: @J... Please see this example of lens flare identified by NASA from one of their Mars rovers which many folks want to believe is a rainbow (in the very dry, very thin air of Mars): Please see this example of lens flare identified by NASA from one of their Mars rovers which many folks want to believe is a rainbow (in the very dry, very thin air of Mars): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_flare#/media/File:MarsPerseveranceRover-Rainbow-20210404.png

Comment: Lens flare can manifest itself in ways beyond specular flare (typically shaped like the lens' aperture), which is what some of you seem to think is the only possible type of flare. There are many other forms of flare that are also caused by light refracted by a lens in undesirable ways.

Comment: The phone case might be involved in producing the flare.

Comment: As an addition to what I already said, I held the iPhone directly at the setting sun and the open sea and could observe this phenomenon on my display. The lines moved and formed, they were not static. I've never seen anything like this before or since. Anyway, thanks for the very detailed answer!

Comment: @J... There's no random squiggle. What is above the horizon could be atmospheric and have nothing to do with the artifact below the horizon, which is shaped roughly like a corner of the glass covering many phone camera lenses or a beveled edge on a cutout for the camera on a phone case.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://streamable.com/m3wv4h (There are no scratches on my lens, at least none visible for me)

Comment: @Aklaus The video tells the story - those are ghosts from the reflections on the water.

Comment: Ghosts are a form of flare...

Comment: @MichaelC I didn't say it wasn't a flare, I said it seems like quite an unusual one (referring to the yellow oval one) that probably wouldn't be produced by a lens in good condition.  I would be checking my lens and any covering very closely for a hairline fracture if I saw that.  While the mars shot *looks* like a rainbow, it is still a much more typical flare than the yellow oval one.  That said, having watched the video, I understand the weird shape.  It is due to the combo of the waves and the shutter speed, i.e. it's because it was a moving flare.

Comment: That is, we aren't seeing the flare shape, we're seeing the path traced by the flare as it moved.  It isn't directly because of the boxy outer glass corner.  It would look quite different at a high enough shutter speed.  When I first saw this image I was even thinking they were maybe bugs flying in front of the camera, but it didn't have signs like the cool wing twirls and the shutter seemed a bit fast for that, but certainly not too fast for a light path like this.